# Angular - ngShow/Hide animation only fires on ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular version v1.2.20 and I'm encountering some weirdness with regards to css transitions when using ng-show/hide. For some reason, if I change the value of a scope object by calling a function through `ng-click` the animation works fine, but if I change it by some other method, say a timeout, or even just calling it in an init function, the element shows, but no animation happens. Here's a small example function that animates when being called from ng-click, but doesn't otherwise.

```
showFlash: (msg, type = "success") ->
  @$.flash =
    "message": msg
    "type": type
  @$timeout =>
    @$.hideFlash()
  , 3000

hideFlash: ->
  @$.flash = null
```

P.S - I'm using Angular Classy for my controller if you're wondering about the funny `@$` syntax.

CSS (Scss)

```
.dashboard-flash-message {
  @include transition ( all 300ms ease-in-out );
  @include transform( translateY(0) );
  background: $primary;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: $dashboard-sidebar-width;

  &.ng-hide {
    @include transform( translateY(100%) );
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping this would be in regular Angular

Comment: @pixelbits `@$.foo` is just the equivalent of `this.$scope.foo`

Comment: Are you using ng-show?

Comment: @pixelbits Yes, `ng-show="flash"` in my div.

Comment: Can you also post your CSS?

Comment: @pixelbits Sure, though I figured my css is fine, since it does animate when calling functions through ng-click.

Comment: I recommend that you use the CSS classes that Angular provides for you to animate. See answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 4 classes that Angular uses to animate ng-show/ng-hide:

> .ng-hide-add
>   .ng-hide-add-active
>   .ng-hide-remove
>   .ng-hide-remove-active

I don't see that you're using them in your stylesheet.

**CSS**

```
.ng-hide-add {
    -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
    -moz-transition:0.5s linear all;
    -o-transition:0.5s linear all;
    transition:0.5s linear all;
    opacity: 1;
}
.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active { 
    opacity: 0;
}

.ng-hide-remove {
   -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
   -moz-transition:0.5s linear all;
   -o-transition:0.5s linear all;
   transition:0.5s linear all;
    opacity: 0;
}
.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active { 
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Script**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
     $scope.show = false;
     $scope.onShow = function() { 
        $scope.show = true;
        $timeout(function() { 
           hideMe();
        },2000);
     }
     function hideMe() {
        $scope.show = false;
     }
});
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nHynY2s36AA5mW4KL3u6?p=preview) that demonstrates how they should be used.

Comment: Thank you! I looked up what classes to use but the docs were a little confusing (it sounded like some of those classes were for intermediate animation steps or something.) Now I get how they work.